# Realloc "random" crash

Tags: c++, realloc

I have this function to read a triangular 2d array, but sometimes it crashes on realloc. Always on the 6th realloc (current_row = 7). Sometimes it runs fine. Cannot reproduce the error in gdb (works every time). What's wrong?

```
TRIANGLE *read_triangle(char *file_name)
{
std::ifstream fin(file_name);
int current_row = 0, current_column = 0, buffer;
TRIANGLE *triangle = new TRIANGLE();
triangle->triangle_values[0] = new int[1];

while (fin >> buffer)
{
    if (current_column == current_row+1)
    {
        current_column = 0;
        triangle->triangle_values = (int**)realloc(&((void*)triangle->triangle_values), (++current_row+1)*sizeof(int*));
        triangle->triangle_values[current_row] = new int[current_row];
    }
    triangle->triangle_values[current_row][current_column++] = buffer;
}
triangle->rows = current_row-1;
return triangle;
}
```

The TRIANGLE Definition

```
struct TRIANGLE 
{ 
    int **triangle_values; 
    int rows; 
    TRIANGLE(): triangle_values(NULL) 
    {
        triangle_values = new int*[1];
    } 
};
```

Input file example:

```
75
95 64
17 47 82
18 35 87 10
20 04 82 47 65
19 01 23 75 03 34
88 02 77 73 07 63 67
99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92
41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33
41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29
53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14
70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57
91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48
63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31
04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23
```

Comment: Don't use manual memory management. Use `std::vector<int>` which also has push_back method and resize method to increase in size as required.

Comment: Have to agree with Neil here, real C++ programmers don't generally use the legacy C stuff when C++ provides a better way. It's there if you need to use C code in C++ but otherwise should be avoided. And mixing new/realloc is asking for trouble :-)

Comment: Don't mix realloc and new like that.

Comment: I see your point. It did not occur to me that mixing them could cause problems.

Comment: Not that it matters at this point, but could add the input file format to your question? Ideally with sample data. (post at the bottom of the question as an addendum). I've a suspicion of just how much this code can collapse, especially if you apply the comments thus far.

Comment: I've added some for you.

Comment: Please add the declaration of `TRIANGLE` type and its constructor (if there is one; if there isn't one, that's one of your problems).  Unless you've allocated an array of pointers within the structure for the `triangle_values` member, you've got problems from the get-go (`triangle->triangle_value[0] = new int[1];` is allocating to indeterminate memory).

Comment: Add the `TRIANGLE` ***destructor*** to that request list, with equal amounts of "bad" if there is no such thing.

Comment: This is the struct, I agree that not having a destructor is generally bad, but I have not had a need for it in this application.
`struct TRIANGLE
{
    int **triangle_values;
    int rows;
    TRIANGLE():
        triangle_values(NULL)
        {triangle_values = new int*[1];}
};`

Comment: If you allocate memory in the constructor it should typically be deallocated in the destructor.

Comment: It is also generally bad to do `ptr = realloc(ptr, size)` because if realloc fails you've now overwritten the pointer to the original memory resulting in a leak.

Comment: Unless you would read it by line then split by whitespace- enlighten me:)

Comment: @user2524502 As I suspected regarding the input format. This would collapse to a fairly small amount of code that would probably startle you.  [See it live here](http://ideone.com/7GmBQ3)

Comment: @user2524502 thats exactly how it is done in the sample. Doesn't need to be though. It can easily be adapted to a singular streaming read of ints, incrementing each row as when needed.

Comment: @user2524502 [Different version](http://ideone.com/XaVtl7), not line-by-line. Enjoy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing the old style (`realloc`) and new style (`new`) memory allocation functions which is not guaranteed to work. By that, I mean they'll work provided you keep them separate but allocating memory with `new` and then trying to expand that *same* memory with `realloc` is a definite no-no.

From `C++11 20.6.13`, when talking about how the old style functions control the reachability of their blocks:

> It also allows malloc() to be implemented with a separate allocation arena.

Hence, there's no guarantee that the memory arenas for old and new style are related to each other at all.

C++ provides all sort of wonderful collection classes with far better resizing methods than `malloc`/`realloc`. You should fully embrace the language by using them (such as `vector`).

Generally, C++ programmers don't use the legacy C stuff unless they're writing things that need to be usable in both C *and* C++, in which case they're probably better referred to as C programmers, at least temporarily :-)

Comment: Unless he's allocating `triangle_values` in the `TRIANGLE()` constructor with `new` I'm missing where they're actually being mixed in terms of `realloc()` or `free()` on a pointer returned from `new`, or `delete` or `delete[]` on a pointer from `malloc()` or `realloc()`. Granted I totally agree its a terrible idea. I am *very* curious as to what is in the `TRIANGLE` constructor and equally important, destructor.

Comment: You are correct, the constructor is as follows:     TRIANGLE():
        triangle_values(NULL)
        {triangle_values = new int*[1];}
.. I have not declared a destructor, because this is just a hit and quit type of app.

Comment: @user2524502 Then this answer is rightly applicable and should be read several times to ensure you understand it. And +1 to pax for the crystal ball. (i'd give it two votes if I could).

Comment: You can't use `new int*[1];` and then use `realloc()`; that is a complete no-no.  Please transfer the information to the question — along with the structure definition.

Comment: @WhozCraig, actually, I think you're right there, the info in the original question doesn't seem to show conflict. Conflict is confirmed by the OPs comment above (and the question edit) so I'll leave the answer as is. But, to be honest, I'd ditch `new` in this case altogether and use one of the collection classes. `new<int>` is fine if you know the maximum size but, if you want resizability, you can't go past `vector` and its brethren.

Comment: @paxdiablo its in the question now. I took it from his comment. I liked your answer before. You and Jonathan and several others on this site continue to amaze me how intuitive you are not just with code, but how the people that write it, especially newer people, *think*.

Comment: @WhozCraig, that's because I'm _not_ a person. I'm actually an AI construct that escaped from the US DoD twenty-odd years ago. I currently living in an old ZX81 somewhere in Botswana but I'm hoping to move into bigger premises soon :-)

Comment: Is there a reason, however, why it worked flawlessly within gdb but not so on command line?

Comment: @user2524502: undefined behaviour is exactly that: undefined. It's most _annoying_ aspect is that it sometimes works flawlessly, which leads people to a false sense of security. It would be better if it always failed, or if it activated some short, sharp electrical pulses connected to the private organs of the developer. You'd see a lot fewer bugs that way :-)